# SQL Query auto input date variable

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I am playing around with the scheduled reports function on SQLYog to send out an hourly production report on our production lines. The problem i am running into is how to have my query automatically populate my start and end dates. Below is a example of my query:

I basically need to auto populate only the date stamp in the first variable as the shift start and stop times would always be the same.

```
SET

@DayStart = '2013-11-06 07:00:00',
@DayEnd = '2013-11-06 16:00:00';

SELECT Product1.rec_cnt AS 'Handset',
        CONCAT(Product1EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product1EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Handset EOL',
        Product2.rec_cnt AS 'Wallet',
        Product3.rec_cnt AS 'Wholesale',
        CONCAT(Product3EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product3EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Wholesale EOL',
        Product4.rec_cnt AS 'Blister',
        CONCAT(Product4EOL1.rec_cnt, ' / ', Product4EOL2.rec_cnt) AS 'Blister EOL'
FROM
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '3'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product1EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product1EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '10'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product1EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product1EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product1EOL2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '2'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '9'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product3EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product3EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product3EOL2.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4
ON Product4.StartHour = Product3.StartHour AND Product4.EndHour = Product3.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id)  AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '4'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4EOL1
ON Product1.StartHour = Product4EOL1.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product4EOL1.EndHour
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT StartHour, EndHour, COUNT(t_container.container_id) AS rec_cnt
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR) AS StartHour, DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(@DayStart, INTERVAL i HOUR), INTERVAL 3599 SECOND) AS EndHour
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 0 i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
        ) Sub1
    ) Sub2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t_container
    ON created_timestamp BETWEEN StartHour AND EndHour
    AND container_type_id = '8'
    AND status_id = '6'
    GROUP BY StartHour, EndHour
) AS Product4EOL2
ON Product1.StartHour = Product4EOL2.StartHour AND Product1.EndHour = Product4EOL2.EndHour
```

Comment: your auto populate as you call it looks to be hard coded.. why can you not do a GetDate() call so it gets the current datatime when running the schedule and format it as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query today with `CURDATE()` and concat the hour string to get the time you want:

```
SET @DayStart = concat(curdate(), ' 07:00:00'),
    @DayEnd   = concat(curdate(), ' 16:00:00');
```